# Open Songs Tab in Music Player in android

Tags: android, android-music-player

the below code always opens with Artists tab in android music player but i want to open Songs tab in android music player when it is launching can this be achieved by intent in android.

```
        Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MUSIC_PLAYER");
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();**
```

Comment: Have you tried opening the music player to the Songs tab yourself, then loading your app and firing this intent?

Comment: @chrylis yes that is firing but i want to open it from my app even songs tab was not opened in music player...

Comment: (1) It's better to use the constant (`MediaStore.INTENT_ACTION_MUSIC_PLAYER`) instead of copying the string in yourself. (2) This intent is now deprecated, as of API 15. (3) I believe this will depend on the particular music-player app the user has selected as the default and can't reliably be controlled from the sending intent.